# Bootstrap modal() Undefined is not a function with npm modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting an error when I try to call $("#myDiv").modal(). The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I have seen this error come from a few different places, and modal() is called with different parameters in the various places. I've seen a lot of questions that say the solution is to include the jquery and bootstrap files in the right order. I find this confusing because I am using jquery and bootstrap npm modules, so I don't include their js files anywhere. How can I get this to work with npm modules?

Comment: have you `bower install bootstrap` it inside your project?

Comment: Ensure bootstrap is after jQuery.

Comment: So what module tool are you using? RequireJS? Browserify? You can't just use npm modules in the browser directly.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding how these modules get used. I installed bootstrap and jquery with npm install and their respective names. My bootstrapped elements seem to be working, and I use "$ = require('jquery')" whenever I want to make ajax calls. I am using gulp with browserify to build the project. Where should I be including the jquery and bootstrap?

Comment: Simply upgrade to Bootstrap v3.3.0. Should  be fixed thanks to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13824

Comment: That didn't work. Where should I be importing bootstrap and jquery?

Answer (score 1):

This issued might be resolved. But I am adding the solution for future reference.

Try checking if the bootstarp jQuery library is included. This problem might be because of a situation where you also include a jQuery library into the web page along with the existing bootstrap jQuery library. Bootstrap will always reference the first included jQuery.

.modal() is included into bootstrap's jQuery. So try including that before.